# Add rectangle on click

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, mouse

I decided to use OpenGL for my project in Qt and I got stuck.
I want to add a rectangle in the place, where I click.
Here is the code I use:

```
void GLWidget::initializeGL()
{
    glClearColor(0.2,0.2,0.2,1);
    glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glViewport(0,0,w1,h1);
}

void GLWidget::paintGL()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}

void GLWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    float x,y;
    x = -10+((e->x()+1)/w1*20);
    y = 10-((e->x()+1)/h1*20);
    qDebug()<<"Position x ="<<x;
    qDebug()<<"Position y ="<<y;
    glColor3f(1,0,0);
    glRectf(x,y,x+1,y+1);
}

void GLWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    updateGL();
}
```

I read that I have to change the glOrtho and glViewport to change the screen coordinates to OpenGL coordinates and I tried to do this, but it isn't working. ;/
In my project w1 and h1 are static const ints, my window has fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

Use paintEvent instead of paintGL and draw a rectangle over your 3d but with QPainter. Look at the Overpainting example.